# What is a druid combo deck?

Tags: hearthstone

I was looking on some websites and I saw some good druid decks that say "combo druid in their description".What exactly is combo druid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A druid combo deck is a deck that gets alot of attack damage in one turn. you need to stall until the right turn when you have the right cards to pull of the combo. It usually involves force of nature (summon 3 2/2 treants) and savage roar (all friendly characters this turn gain +2 attack). this does 14 damage in one turn which is really good. especially if the other hero is damaged. There are other combos but this is the main one.

Comment: @jack graveny thanks for edit have not played druid in a while forgot it was force of nature

Comment: It's worth noting that the combo often involves innervate and/or Thaurissan to play two savage roars along with the FoN. This deals 22 damage and can easily deal 30+ with other minions on the board.

Comment: Also note, it's at LEAST 14 damage in one turn, assuming you have no minions in play.